# Bash script for Angstrom

Tags: bashrc, angstrom

I have written a bash script to automate cross-compiling an OpenCV program:

```
echo "Compiling started for: $1"
if [[ $1 == *.c ]]
then
    gcc -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $1 .c` $1 `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
elif [[ $1 == *.cpp ]]
then
    g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $1 .cpp` $1 `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
else
    echo "Only c or c++ files"
fi
echo "Output: ${1%.*}"
```

But now I noticed that there does not exist a bashrc at the Angstrom distribution. So what can I do?

Comment: Make sure to put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script (a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line), otherwise your script might be executed in a different shell.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify something. `.bashrc` is just for configuring your bash interpreter. You can set things like, how should your prompt look etc... It does not mean anything special if it does not exist, you can just create it, and if its a proper linux it will be read by default.

However you can check what kind of interpretation enviorment your user is in by taking a lookg on `/etc/passwd`, on the line with your user, there will be what it is like: `/bin/bash`

If for some reason, bash is not your default shell, you [can read this blogpost](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-bash-as-your-default-shell/) for setting it to.